# Get multiple checkbox data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How I can get multiple checkbox data-attribute (only checked)?

I can get checkbox values, but not data attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//export upc
  $('#export_upc').click(function(){
    var arr = $('.checkboxes:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);
}); 
</script>
```

I tried `return this.data("upc")`, but this is not working.

Comment: some markup would be helpful

Comment: `$(this).data('upc')` or `this.dataset.upc `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` represents DOM element. You should use `jquery` object `$(this)` instead.

```
$(this).data("upc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$(this).attr('upc')`

Comment: `$(this).data('upc')` or `this.dataset.upc`